# Make entire element a clickable area in navigation bar

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In the below code when I hover over the navigation items like Home/About/Contact/Popular Posts, only the portion of `<a>` is getting background color.

But I want the complete Home Block to get highlighted when hovered.

And at the same time with my flexbox I want my extra space to be distributed between the list items as done below.

```css
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
}

nav {
  background: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.9);
  border: 5px solid rgba(150, 175, 200, 0.4);
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav>ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}

nav>ul>li {
  list-style: none;
  flex: 1;
}

nav>ul>li>a {
  padding: 10px;
}

nav>ul>li :hover {
  background: rgb(240, 100, 100);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Popular Posts</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method #1**

Remove the borders around `nav`:

```
nav {   
    background: rgba(10,10,10,0.9);
    /* border: 5px solid rgba(150,175,200,0.4); <---- REMOVE */
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I'm assuming when you say "complete block" and "entire flex item" you mean hover over everything. But if you still want the border, just ignore the step above.

**Method #2**

Add `display: block` to `a` elements:

```
nav > ul > li > a {
    padding: 10px;
    display: block; /* NEW */
}
```

An anchor element will, by default, extend only the length of its content. By making it a block element it will extend the full width of its container.

```css
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
}

nav {
  background: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.9);
  /* border : 5px solid rgba(150,175,200,0.4); */
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav>ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}

nav>ul>li {
  list-style: none;
  flex: 1;
}

nav>ul>li>a {
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
}

nav>ul>li :hover {
  background: rgb(240, 100, 100);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Popular Posts</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

Simply make it

```
nav > ul :hover {
    background : rgb(240, 100, 100);
}
```

and it should work (take out the `li`)

Comment: The only issue with this solution is that the clickable region doesn't expand. So yes, the coloring expands on hover, but the user won't be able to click the link unless they're over the text.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you missed ? :

```
 nav > ul > li > a {
  display: block;
}
```

demo below

```css
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
}
nav {
  background: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.9);
  border: 5px solid rgba(150, 175, 200, 0.4);
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
nav > ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}
nav > ul > li {
  list-style: none;
  flex: 1;
}
nav > ul > li > a {
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
}
nav > ul > li:hover {
  background: rgb(240, 100, 100);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Nav BAr</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Popular Posts</a>
      </li>

    </ul>

  </nav>

</body>

</html>
```